# method endgame() cannot be called

Tags: c#

So for the main class, I only have this code. Calling the cClass. **THIS IS A DICE GAME**

```
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cClass cs = new cClass();

    }
}
```

For the Constructor class, which is cClass i have this code. The method `endgame()` is not working. This is where the problem located the when the dice game done battling, the `endgame()` is not working.

```
class cClass
{
    
    public cClass()
    {
        Intialize();
    }

    public void Intialize()
    {
        sClass.round = 1;
        while (sClass.com < 3 && sClass.player < 3)
        {
        start:
            Console.WriteLine("Round (" + sClass.round + ")");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess: ( 1 - 6)");
            sClass.guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (sClass.guess >= 7)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Only enter number ranges from 1 - 6");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                goto start;
            }
            sClass.playgame();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe dice rolled is...");
            Console.WriteLine(sClass.playerdie);

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer guessed: " + sClass.guess);
            Console.WriteLine("Computer guessed: " + sClass.comguess);
            if ((sClass.comguess == sClass.playerdie) && (sClass.guess == sClass.playerdie))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nBoth guessed correctly! Restarting the round!\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Player points: " + sClass.player);
                Console.WriteLine("Computer points: " + sClass.com);
            }
            else if (sClass.guess == sClass.playerdie)
            {
                sClass.player++;
                Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer guessed correctly you won!\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Player points: " + sClass.player);
                Console.WriteLine("Computer points: " + sClass.com);
                sClass.round++;
            }
            else    if (sClass.comguess == sClass.playerdie)
            {
                sClass.com++;
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer guessed correctly you lost...\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Player points: " + sClass.player);
                Console.WriteLine("Computer points: " + sClass.com);
                sClass.round++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNo one got it correct restarting the round!\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Player points: " + sClass.player);
                Console.WriteLine("Computer points: " + sClass.com);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
        endgame();
    }
    
    

    public void endgame()
    {
        if (sClass.player > sClass.com)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player Win! Player vs Computer");
            Console.WriteLine("               (" + sClass.player + ") vs (" + sClass.com + ")");
        }
        else if (sClass.player < sClass.com)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Computer Win! Player vs Computer");
            Console.WriteLine("               (" + sClass.player + ") vs (" + sClass.com + ")");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Its a draw! Player vs Computer");
            Console.WriteLine("                (" + sClass.player + ") vs (" + sClass.com + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

then I also have a static class , which is sClass.

```
 static class sClass
{
    public static int dice = 1;
    public static int playerdie;
    public static int guess;
    public static int comguess;
    public static int player;
    public static int com;
    public static int round;
    public static Random r = new Random();

    
    public static void playgame()
    {
        
        comguess = r.Next(1, 6);
        playerdie = rolldie();

    }

    public static int rolldie()
    {
        int die = r.Next(1, 6);
        return die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Method `endgame()` in cClass is not initiating when the battle of dice is done, method `endgame()` is not displaying...

Comment: Why is your method not working? Do you get an error message? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @SomeBody no error.

Comment: if `endgame()` is not working, then perhaps the code is still stuck in the while loop, have you debugged to see if it can reach the method? Or additionally, shouldn't the while check be an OR-statement? `while (sClass.com < 3 || sClass.player < 3)`

Comment: Yes I already debugged it but when the game is done , it's not going to `endgame()` @Steven

Comment: When I change the or `&&` to and `||` it keeps the game back to round 1. @Steven

Comment: Could you define what you mean when the "game is done"? I'm assuming that it's when either the computer or player has reached a score of 3, and it currently checks on both simultaniously

Comment: Yes the game is done when the computer and player has reached a score of 3 then , `endgame()` needs to display who wins @Steven

Comment: It seemed to give me end game summary too.

Comment: Please DO NOT use "goto". Whoever taught you to use it, do not go for advice to them again. Read a good book that explains how to program properly.

Comment: Can you recommend something ? Like Link on which is better to use? anyway thankyou! @nvoigt

Comment: @XmPar Try `continue` instead of `goto`, then it'll go at the start of the while loop again. (This works for other loops like `for` and `foreach` as well)

Comment: In your case, a goto is just a loop someone was too lazy to program.

Comment: Thankyou I get it ! @nvoigt , Can you help me with my problem facing right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you just said that there is no error. I think you just missed only 1 code. In `cClass.cs` Go to the `Initialize()` method, go at the `endgame()` then put the `Console.ReadLine` above the `endgame`

```
endgame();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Then it will show the `endgame` method.

Comment: You should explain why this may work. Adding the `Console.ReadLine` stops the program and waits for user input. If this is a case of a program ending so quickly that a user cannot see the output, waiting for user input would let them read the output before ending the program.

Comment: @MichaelM I copy his code, Then run on my end and put the `Console.ReadLine();` below `endgame();` and it worked.

Comment: Yes, it worked, but that's not what the issue is. The issue is you need to explain WHY it works in order for it to be an effective answer

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your while loop says that it's checking on both simultaniously:

```
while (sClass.com < 3 && sClass.player < 3)
```

I said formerly if it should be an OR-statement, but that didn't work, because then either of them would still be true, continue-ing the while loop.

So it'll only stop the while loop if all statements are false.

Perhaps this code will work:

```
while (!(sClass.com >= 3 && sClass.player >= 3))
```

What I did now is reversing the while check, and now it checks if both are still false, and the `!` will reverse that `false` to `true`. So if either of the scores becomes 3 now, it'll go out of the while loop.

Comment: Still the same continue-ing the while loop. This is the best of 5 who will first reached the score of 3 is the winner then it will display the `endgame` method.  , I Already go to round 8 and still no displaying of winner which is the `endgame()` method.

Comment: I did your code and no error appears, but the while loop keeps continue-ing @Steven

Comment: My mistake, I think I just did the same thing as in the first while loop, so this doesn't improve. I think the first while loop already works what should be intended, so the problem is not related on the while loop then.

Comment: Please do help me with this steven.

Comment: If the problem is not on the while loop (going with the fact that it only continues the loop if both statements are true), then I'm afraid I cannot see the problem. So I'm gonna assume the problem is that the while-loop keeps continueïng somehow. Try debugging again and the moment it hits the while check. hover over the values of `sClass.com` and `sClass.player` and see if they still fit the criteria. you can also hover over the `&&` so you can view if the full criteria results true or false.